# @forward must come first but thinks it isn't

Tags: javascript, sass

I have a `.sass` file defined like this:

```
@forward './settings'
@use './generic'
@use './elements'
@use './utilities'
```

When I try and load the app (a Vue3 + Vuetify3 + Vite stack) and run via Vite, I get the following error:

```
3:25:20 PM [vite] Internal server error: @forward rules must be written before any other rules.
  ╷
2 │ @forward './settings'
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  node_modules/vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass 2:1  root stylesheet
```

Note that in the corresponding sass file, the `@forward` directive is the very first line. Why does vite think it's the second line? How do I debug what the file is being masticated into, since it seems clear that something is being inserted automatically into the first line that causes the `@forward` error?

Comment: Are you including that in any other sass file?

Comment: `main.sass` is only included (as far as I or a full text search can tell) in one other file, a javascript file that it is also the first line of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with variables configuration in vite.config.js, maybe change in latest 3.0.0-alpha.11 vuetify template generation

just comment lines in preprocessorOptions

````js
preprocessorOptions: {
  // sass: { additionalData: `@import ${srcPath}\n` },
  // scss: { additionalData: `@import ${srcPath};\n` },
},```
````

Comment: I do think this was the cause - something was happening in the preprocessing.